# Console.KeyAvailable - How do I reset this boolean?

Tags: c#, boolean

using C# here. I'm creating a console app. I have two methods that scroll text instead of just instantly displaying it on the screen. One works the same as Console.Write() and the other works like Console.WriteLine(). The difference is there is a 30 ms delay between each character. I'm trying to make it so that when you hold down a key it speeds up to a 5ms delay between each character. The problem is that once you hit a key the Console.KeyAvailable is true and won't reset, and so it keeps going with only a 5ms delay. Is there a way to set this back to false, or something else I can do to accomplish this? Here is my code:

```
    //Console.Write() version
    static void RPGWrite(string write)
    {
        char[] writearray = write.ToCharArray();
        int writearraycount = writearray.Count();
        for (int x = 0; x < writearraycount; x++)
        {
            Console.Write(Convert.ToString(writearray[x]));
            if (Console.KeyAvailable == false)
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30);
            else
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5);                   
        }            
    }
    //Console.WriteLine() version
    static void RPGWriteLine(string write)
    {
        char[] writearray = write.ToCharArray();
        int writearraycount = writearray.Count();
        for (int x = 0; x < writearraycount; x++)
        {
            Console.Write(Convert.ToString(writearray[x]));
            if (Console.KeyAvailable == false)
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30);
            else
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5);
        }
        Console.Write("\n");
    }
```

Comment: AFAIK, to set [`KeyAvailable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.keyavailable.aspx) back to false is that you actually need to read the key from the stream (e.g. by using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3h8xffw.aspx))

Comment: I can't use any method that requires input. If I do that it will stop entirely and wait for user input. The method is supposed to keep writing. So if I can't do that with KeyAvailable what are my options?

Comment: Console.ReadKey() kinda works, but the problem is the characters are shown from the key I hold down.

Comment: Do Console.ReadKey(true), then.

Comment: `Console.ReadKey(true)` should result in the character not being echoed to the window (that's what [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3h8xffw.aspx) says anyway)

Comment: Ahh ok thanks. I'll have to adjust a few things now, but I think I can get it to work now.

Comment: No problem, I've moved some of the discussion from the comments to an answer in case anyone has a similar scenario or issue to resolve like you have (hope that's OK).

Answer (score 4):

[nkvu - moving items from the comments to here in case it helps anyone else]

AFAIK, to set [`KeyAvailable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.keyavailable.aspx) back to false is that you actually need to read the key from the stream (e.g. by using [`Console.ReadKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3h8xffw.aspx)).

Using `Console.ReadKey(true)` will read a character from the stream without echoing back to the console for the user to see - though note the remarks in the MSDN documentation about a key press of Alt, Ctrl or Shift key by itself.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that ended up working for me:

```
    //Console.Write() version
    static void RPGWrite(string write)
    {
        char[] writearray = write.ToCharArray();
        int writearraycount = writearray.Count();
        for (int x = 0; x < writearraycount; x++)
        {
            if (Console.KeyAvailable == false)
            {
                Console.Write(Convert.ToString(writearray[x]));
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write(Convert.ToString(writearray[x]));
                if (x < (writearraycount - 1))
                {
                    x++;
                    Console.Write(Convert.ToString(writearray[x]));
                }
                if (x < (writearraycount - 2))
                {
                    x++;
                    Console.Write(Convert.ToString(writearray[x]));
                }
                if (x < (writearraycount - 3))
                {
                    x++;
                    Console.Write(Convert.ToString(writearray[x]));
                }
                if (x < (writearraycount - 4))
                {
                    x++;
                    Console.Write(Convert.ToString(writearray[x]));
                }
                Console.ReadKey(true);
            }
        }           
    }
    //Console.WriteLine() version
    static void RPGWriteLine(string write)
    {
        char[] writearray = write.ToCharArray();
        int writearraycount = writearray.Count();
        for (int x = 0; x < writearraycount; x++)
        {
            if (Console.KeyAvailable == false)
            {
                Console.Write(Convert.ToString(writearray[x]));
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write(Convert.ToString(writearray[x]));
                if (x < (writearraycount - 1))
                {
                    x++;
                    Console.Write(Convert.ToString(writearray[x]));
                }
                if (x < (writearraycount - 2))
                {
                    x++;
                    Console.Write(Convert.ToString(writearray[x]));
                }
                if (x < (writearraycount - 3))
                {
                    x++;
                    Console.Write(Convert.ToString(writearray[x]));
                }
                if (x < (writearraycount - 4))
                {
                    x++;
                    Console.Write(Convert.ToString(writearray[x]));
                }
                Console.ReadKey(true);
            }
        }
        Console.Write("\n");
    }
```